# Iterating JS array of objects in html & get selected 'object' in JS : LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

Here is what I'm trying to do( searched but not finding related to this)

I've list of meeting rooms  which I maintained like this in LWC JS file :

```
 meetingRooms = [
    {name:'A-10', capacity:'10'},
    {name:'A-20', capacity:'6'},
    {name:'A-30', capacity:'15'},
    {name:'B-10', capacity:'12'},
    {name:'B-20', capacity:'6'}
];
```

Now I iterate this using lightning tile in html file like this:

```
 <lightning-card title ="All Rooms" >
    <template for:each={meetingRooms} for:item= "room">
        <div key={room.name}>
            <div class="slds-p-around_medium lgc-bg" onclick = {tileclickHandler}>
        
                    <lightning-tile label={room.name} href="/path/to/somewhere">
                        <p class="slds-truncate" title={room.capacity}>{room.capacity}</p>
                    </lightning-tile>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
</lightning-card>
```

What I want is to get **selected** object(i.e. each individual room) when 'tileclickHandler' is called on clicking div element.
I don't want individual properties(like room.name or room.capacity) but whole object. I want to pass that object in some event later on.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the room later:

```
<div class="slds-p-around_medium lgc-bg" data-room-name={room.name} onclick={tileclickHandler}>
```

...

```
titleClickHandler(event) {
  this.selectedRoom = this.meetingRooms.find(room => room.name === event.target.dataset.roomName);
```

To be clear, anything you put in to an attribute (e.g. a `data-*` attribute) will be coerced in to a String, which is why you can't just:

```
data-room={room}
```

You need to have a unique identifier that you can search on somehow, and this is the usual way we would do so, is by using the `key` as a separate property we can search on.

You can see a functional example where I do this in my [drag-and-drop demo component](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/zTluHmgVwgmSIufHEADa/src/app.html).

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox.  But unfortunately problem is still there.  When i alert event.target.dataset.roomName, it is coming at undefined

Comment: @sfdc_Qrius Make sure your attribute is on the correct element.